# Adding space between items in an owl carousel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

How do I add space between items in an owl carousel? I've tried using `stagePadding` but it adds space to the left of the first item. Margin does not work either. Can you help me?

HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
  navigation : true
  });
});
```

```css
#owl-demo .item{
  padding: 30px 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WZwr2a_lFWY" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dLymsYC7Kmo" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M46FRJsB0Qw" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6eEZ7DJMzuk" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nRYCLOTRAK4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eDEFolvLn0A" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nnVjsos40qk" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QqsvrV1_XEA" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/G8GaQdW2wHc" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <div class = "item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0nPlIi685DU" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add to the code: **autoWidth:true**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     
      $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        navigation : true,
        autoWidth:true,
      });
     
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pohnvm01/

Comment: Thank you!! This worked, however there's extra space to the right of the last item in the owl carousel. How should I fix that?

Comment: May be add loop:true

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. See my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/1v9x0g63/3/

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
         
          $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
            navigation : true,
            margin: 10 // for example

          });
         
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I tried it with margin but it didn't work :(